# Will approving git pull request lose changes?

Tags: git

I have git repository which has master branch and a develop branch. Developers check out code from develop branch and create feature branches.

Imagine a scenario where a developer named A spins a develop branch and create a feature branch. Mean time some of the developers has merged their feature branches to the develop branch. When A completes their task, commit the changes to the feature branch and issue a pull request to develop branch. Before issuing the pull request the developer A didn't pull changes from the develop branch to the feature branch.

Will approving the pull request cause any issue like losing the changes of other developers?

Comment: Only if there are merge conflicts and a poor job is done resolving those conflicts.Git doesn't merge snapshots, it merges changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. What you are describing is standard [Git Flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow). In this scenario, all that is being compared is Developer A's feature branch against the `develop` branch *after* the other commits have been made. Note that only commits are compared, not snapshots.

If there are merge conflicts between what Developer A has done and the work of the other developers, then this will be highlighted as a merge conflict at the point of creation of the PR from Developer A.